# Custom routing in Web API 2. Failing to reach controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method inside of my controller which I am trying to reach:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("UpdateTitle")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateTitle(Guid playlistId, string title)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        PlaylistManager.UpdateTitle(playlistId, title);

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I have another method in the controller which is also a POST and is the method which is actually being hit by my request (erroneously):

```
[HttpPost]
public PlaylistDto Create(PlaylistDto playlistDto)
```

Here's what my raw request information looks like:

[image]

Here's my routing:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    //  TODO: Create test cases for custom routing.
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("UpdateTitle", "Playlist/UpdateTitle/{playlistId}/{title}");

        //  TODO: What does this do?
        // Web API routes
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Why on earth is it redirecting to the Create method? The signature looks correct to me for being routed to the UpdateTitle method.

Comment: MapHttpAttributeRoutes is to enable attribute routing. Have a look here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 And try out http://getglimpse.com/ for your route debugging and many other needs.

Comment: I can't see the image (yay for imgur being blocked by corp proxies :-/), but your route config doesn't take actions into account, so as far as the route mapper is concerned, both methods have the same route.

Comment: Naw. The issue is definitely that you can't POST multiple params in the body for web API. Goes against their rules. Should either be PATCHing, re-work my architecture so I can just PUT an update, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class that contains all your form data. You may be able to use your PlaylistDto class for this:

```
public class PlaylistDto
{
    public Guid PlaylistId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your UpdateTitle method to:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("UpdateTitle")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateTitle(PlaylistDto Dto)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        PlaylistManager.UpdateTitle(Dto.playlistId, Dto.title);

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Finally change your routing as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    //  TODO: Create test cases for custom routing.
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UpdateTitle",
            routeTemplate: "Playlist/UpdateTitle",
            defaults: new { controller = "PlaylistController", action = "UpdateTitle" }
         );    

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare like this, see if it helps (since I believe you're sending your parameters in the body of the request:

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateTitle([FromBody]Guid playlistId, [FromBody]string title)
```

Comment: I can see why that would help... but, I'm at a bit of a loss. It's a POST request... doesn't that imply all the info is in the body anyway? Why the need to be explicit in Web API when it worked fine in MVC4? ALSO, you're not allowed to decorate multiple parameters with FromBody.

Comment: @SeanAnderson _doesn't that imply all the info is in the body anyway?_ - Nope.  You can have both QueryString and Body parameters in the same request.  I've worked only with WebAPI, but I noticed that WebAPI and MVC are somewhat different (different APIs available) - so it is my understanding that those are not the same thing.  Not sure about multiple parameters - don't have code handy atm to check.